# Stop ScrollView collapsing when using keyboard and allow scrolling of elements behind?

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout, android-softkeyboard

I know there are a few questions about this on SO but I haven't found one to solve my exact issue, nor have I been able to figure it out from other answers.

I have a layout with a few `EditText` boxes, and the bottom of which is fairly big and stretches from about halfway down the page to the bottom. When I activate the keyboard, this EditText is then shrunk to reach just above where the keyboard stops. This isn't an issue on devices with larger screens, but on some of the older devices I can see that the box is barely visible.

Is there a way that I can wrap my layout into a `ScrollView` to allow the box to stay the same size, and let the user just scroll the page to see any items hidden by the keyboard (i.e. making the area above the keyboard the "window" but keeping the same sized views inside)?

A good example of what I mean is in the HTC's Mail setup screen where when creating a new account, you can scroll the screen to see the content hidden behind the keyboard when it's active. There are probably others, but that came to mind.

Here is the XML for my page, as you can see it's quite simple (my Strings are placeholders, so nobody point that out :P).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Contact Us"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/title"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:background="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:text="Your Email:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextFrom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/email"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bordered"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subject"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextFrom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextFrom"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:text="Your Subject:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSubject"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/subject"
    android:layout_below="@+id/subject"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bordered"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextSubject"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:text="Your Message:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/message"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bordered"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp" />
```

I know there are a few edits to the `AndroidManifest.xml` which can be made, and I'm pretty sure this is doable, I just can't seem to find the right combo!

Any help is appreciated, if I didn't make it clear enough just say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is far beyond what I had in mind originally, so I'm not going to accept this unless nothing better comes up.

What I'm doing now to solve the issue is I added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to my activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I tested a bunch of screen sizes and figured that 800px height was roughly the limit for when it gets a bit difficult to read due to the keyboard, so I added the following code to my `onCreateView()`:

```
DisplayMetrics screen = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(screen);
if(screen.heightPixels < 800){
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
}
```

It'd make sense to work out roughly which setting is likely to have more devices (`>= 800` or `< 800` and flip the if statement accordingly, just to make it more efficient (although it won't be noticeable).

As I said this is a workaround rather than an ideal answer to the question, so more answers please! :)

Edit: Didn't account for density, now using `if(screen.displayDPI < 160 && screen.heightPixels < 800){`